# How to count number of elements pressent on screen

Tags: appium

In my application i wanna count number of elements pressent in on div using appium 1.7.1 for ios
Example in my application room wise i wanna count in one room how many switches are pressent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can able to count number of switches in one room.. Below code is working fine for me

> TouchAction touch1 = new TouchAction(driver);
>
> touch1.tap (80, 300).perform();
>
> List optionCount =driver.findElementsByClassName("XCUIElementTypeImage");
>
> System.out.println(optionCount.size()-1); Blockquote

Comment: I believe this is in response to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use findElements, which will you return you a list of all elements matching your query. You'll then use standard Java to grab the number of elements in the list.

Usage examples: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/findelement-and-findelements-command/